# What does "to squinch one's eyes closed" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Please explain me the meaning of "to squinch one's eyes closed". Is it the act of closing eyes.

Example:
"Squinching her eyes closed, she stepped through the archway."

Thank you!

Comment: I think that _squinch_ is a mashup of _squeeze_ plus _pinch_: If you simultaneously squeeze your eyes and pinch them, you thereby squinch them.

Comment: Could you please explain more about "pinch eyes". I imagine that this is the action of closing eyes with force because of scaring or something like that. Is it right?

Comment: Nhu_Doan: It refers to a tightening of the muscles in the face around the eyes, not necessarily closing the eyes entirely. _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ speculates that the source words are _squint_ (not _squeeze_) and _pinch_, which would suggest that a person with squinched eyes hasn't closed them entirely. That is indeed the meaning that MW gives for _squinch_, but there are instances like this one from Edward Hope, _Spanish Omelette_ (1937): "She closed her eyes, squinching them tight, as if to clear them." There, I think _squinching" is much more akin to _squeezing_.

Comment: @SvenYargs, thank you so much for your clearly explanation. I got it now.

Comment: @Elian, thank you so much for your help. I have already checked the page you advised, but still being confused. I think the explanation from Sven Yargs is well fit in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Figuratively, this may mean that she is nervous about whatever may happen. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, it's actually that she is nervous. It is from a story. The girl had to read a poem to open the door at the ledge of a hill which led to a secret revel. She failed in her first attempt. And then she made another try. I asked this because I would like to know exactly whether she closed her eyes tightly or haft closed and haft opened to see what happening. And now, after discussing, I figured out that she closed eyes tightly.